# ESLint - Angular2 Anotations

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, eslint

I use *ESLint* and *gulp-eslint*. Is there a way to activate linter rules for Angular2 anotations?

```
@Component( {
  selector: 'example',
  styleUrls: ['app.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app.html', //Linter should warn cause the semicolon
})
//Linter should warn in case of a blank line between componente and class

export class App {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [eslint-plugin-angular](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular#rules-specific-for-angular-1-or-2) to get Angular-specific rules for ESLint. From there, if you want specific rules that don't yet exist, you could see about adding them to the plugin.

```
plugins:
    - angular

rules:
    # Whichever rules you like

globals:
    angular: true

settings:
    angular: 2
```